# Intensity of gamma rays

Tags: experimental-physics

possibly a silly question but I’m working on analysing the gamma ray spectra for 152Eu and after fitting all the peaks, I’ve worked out the area of the peaks. 
I want to perform an energy calibration but I think I need the intensity first.
The parameters I have are the counts, the channel number, sigma and the area.

How do I go about calculating the intensity?
The only equations I’ve been able to find have been with area and efficiency, and I havent got the efficiency of the detector because that’s the end game and what I need to calculate at the end.

If i use 
I=I0exp(-ux) i dont know I0.
I can’t use I=P/A either

Comment: Confused as to what you mean by *energy calibration*. Do you mean channel number to energy relationship, or are you trying to determine the efficiency of the detector versus energy?

Comment: For now my tasks are to perform an energy calibration with my preaquired data using channel to energy, and once the energy calibration is done I have to find the efficiency of the detector. I was asked to find the intensity but I’m not sure where that fits in.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the energies and relative intensities of Eu-152 gamma rays at a Chart of the Nuclides or Table of Nuclides website. Someone probably has them compiled somewhere, too. If your source is purely Eu-152, then use the relative instensities and the areas of the matching energy peaks to develop an efficiency vs energy graph.

The efficiency of the detector will be higher at lower energies and smoothly drop.   How much it drops depends on the type of detector.

Detector efficiencies are usually relative relative to some standard detector such as a 2"x2" NaI(Tl) crystal measuring 667 keV (or 1173 keV) at some specific distance (I can't pull it off the top of my head right now!). But the important thing is the curve for your detector.

Comment: In the experiments I've done (in gamma ray spectroscopy),  the absolute efficiency was not of interest. All you typically want is the efficiency as a function of energy, up to an arbitrary normalization.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I’m trying to do the energy calibration graph right now and I know it’s supposed to be a straight line, but I’m not getting a straight line. Am I correct in plotting the channel number on the x axis and the counts on the y?

Comment: No, plot energy on the $y$ and centroid channel on the $x$.

Comment: Oh thank you! I’ve gathered the counts and the centroid channel # of the peaks in the 152Eu spectrum, how do i derive the energy from this?

Comment: You should research what the energies of the Eu-152 gammas are.

Comment: They are well-documented.

Comment: So it’s the known energies that’s used for the calibrations i see thank you very much!

Comment: @BenCrowell It is not all unusual that one needs to measure absolute activities, for example for safety or regulatory reasons.